# Efficient Way of Making new Data Frame

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this? Note in the original data.frame the names are in brackets and I would like to count the number of runs each person did, but remake a new dataframe without the brackets.

```
df = read.csv(filename)
matrix = matrix(nrow=4, ncol=2, dimnames = list(c("John","Aaron","Mary","Jennifer"), c("Total Runs","Percentage of Total Runs")))

TotalRunCount = as.numeric(NROW(na.omit(df)))
matrix[1, 1] = as.numeric(length(which(df$name=="[John]")))
matrix[2, 1] = as.numeric(length(which(df$name=="[Aaron]")))
matrix[3, 1] = as.numeric(length(which(df$name=="[Mary]")))
matrix[4, 1] = as.numeric(length(which(df$name=="[Jennifer]")))

CountRun = as.data.frame(matrix)
```

Comment: Knowing that we don't have access to your `filename`, it would be more helpful if you provided actual sample data. The best method is `dput(x)`, where `x` is a reasonably-sized frame, just big enough to get the point across and derive something with the sample code. Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Note that if you convert `df$name` to factor: `df$name <- as.factor(df$name)` then taking the `summary`: `counts <- summary(df$name)` will give you a count vector to populate the matrix column.  BTW, you should avoid using specific R language terms, e.g. "matrix" as variable names to avoid confusion.

Comment: does `table(df$name)` help you get what you want?